# How to automate adding Tagged Value Types and editing of templates in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to automate the following tasks in Enterprise Architect:

1. Add new tagged Value types

**2. Make certain changes to DDL Templates** (e.g add system versioning to a table by replacing the DDL Create Table Template for MySQL with another template, that contains a "With System Versioning" clause)

Is there a way to achieve this via scripting (https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/automation/automation_interface.html), by writing an Add In (https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.1/automation/addins_2.html) or by using MDG Technologies (https://sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/modeling_tools/mdgtechnologies_2.html) for Enterprise Architect?

Thank you in advance for all comments, answers and ideas!

Comment: Providing your code in the question would help spotting the issue.

Comment: The Problem is that i do not have any code :)

Comment: If you don't have any code how have you *"already tried to achieve this with a VBScript"*?

Comment: It was just an approach that lead into the void. I now have removed this sentence from my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding tagged value types is definitely possible.

I use this code in my [Model wrapper](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/Model.cs)

This is C#, but the translation to any other supported language such as VBScript is trivial.

```cs
public void addTaggedValueType(string tagName, string tagDescription, string tagDetail)
{
    global::EA.PropertyType taggedValueType = (global::EA.PropertyType)this.wrappedModel.PropertyTypes.AddNew(tagName, "");
    taggedValueType.Description = tagDescription;
    taggedValueType.Detail = tagDetail;
    taggedValueType.Update();
}
```

I don't think the API has a feature to update DDL templates directly, but you can deploy those with an MDG.

And you can include an MDG into your add-in. See [this add-in class](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Toolpack/blob/master/GlossaryManager/GlossaryManagerAddin.cs) for an example

Normally tagged value types are also distributed in an MDG and not created directly by an add-in.

Comment: The question is asking about a solution using VBScript. If there is a C# specific question along these lines please post your solution there.

Comment: @Lankymart Where do you see the OP asking for a VBScript only answer? The main question is how to do this with the EA API. The actual language used to use this API is irrelevant and the translation is trivial.

Comment: The question is tagged VBScript, it's a VBScript question. If it's broader than that, then it's just not a good fit for [so].

Comment: @Lankymart I'm not sure. Even with only the Enterprise Architect tag is would be specific enough IMO.

Comment: Tbh, the question isn't great. The OP hasn't provided any code at all, but the question is tagged VBScript. So it may be about Enterprise Architect but in the context of VBScript which [Enterprise Architect supports](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/automation/the_scripter_window.html). Anything else is just broadening the question.